# How to stop Linux "read" system call from blocking?

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

How can a read Linux system call be unblocked in C++? If I have for example in a thread the following loop
:

```
bool shouldRun;

void foo(){
  while(shouldRun){
    length = read( file_descriptor, buffer, buffer_length);
    //do something
  }
  return;
}

main(){
  shouldRun = true;
  std::thread myThread(foo);
  //do some other stuff
  shouldRun = false;
  //-->here I want to unblock "read" in foo
}
```

Generally the read method should block, I only want to unblock it when needed.

Comment: How can any function call be aborted?

Comment: @dandan78 I don't understand your comment. Please clarify. EDIT: Unblock could be a better taxonomy here, I agree.

Comment: Close the file descriptor from another thread?

Comment: You can `pthread_kill()` the thread, provided you configured the given signal properly in the thread. Thus the call to `read()` will return with error `EINTR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

This will make the file descriptor non-blocking.

Comment: 'Generally the read method should block, I only want to unblock it when needed'

Comment: You can always clear the flag when you want it to block again. Alternatively, you can use select or poll with a zero timeout to see if the file descriptor would block and the only call the read if the file descriptor would not block.

Answer (score 0):

the libc read() function internally invoke syscall in kernel side.
The (linux) kernel region is generally not support abort due to its design (yes this can make process non-killable in some case)

To archive your goal, you should make read() non-blocking so that the kernel call return immediately, or check if data ready before read() using select().

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the read call is waiting for data to become available and it's blocking because of this.

That's why I'd suggest you check if data is available before reading:

```
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>

    ...

    int count;
    ioctl(file_descriptor, FIONREAD, &count);
```